# update all rows with adding text before it

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is how my table is

```
create table tab (id INT, fullname varchar(100));
```

Data is

```
insert into tab values
(1,'Full Name 1'),
(2,'Full Name 2'),
(3,'Full Name 3'),
(4,'Full Name 4'),
(5,'Full Name 5'),
(6,'Full Name 6');
```

I want to update the table with `fullname` as `My Full Name is + actuallfullname`. e.g. data for id 1 should be `My Full Name is Full Name 1`.

Any idea how to get this done in one query?

Using below query, it would be executing n times as I have so many records.

```
UPDATE tab SET fullname='My Full Name is Full Name 1';
```

### [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1f1f/1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**.

```
UPDATE tab 
SET fullname = CONCAT('My Full Name is ', fullname)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c2fc/1)

Comment: more 7 minutes to go to accept answer.. I hate this **FEATURE** of SO.

Comment: @FahimParkar hehe just take you time :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use MySQL's [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
UPDATE tab SET fullname = CONCAT('My Full Name is ', fullname);
```

But does this really belong in the database?  Sounds like something one would normally perform at the presentation layer of one's application.

Answer (score 2):

Ref [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE tab SET fullname=CONCAT('My Full Name is ',fullname);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tab SET fullname = CONCAT('My Full Name is ' , fullname)
```